# Authentication in Laravel 4 with different MySQL engines

Tags: php, mysql, passwords, laravel-4, password-encryption

OK I have got a user table with a username and hashed password  in a db. Works fine on my local machine but when I export to a different server login doesn't work (ie bad password)

I have checked and the hashed value looks the same, the only difference I found is that a different engine is used, I have InnoDB on my local mysql and it is MyISAM on the live server, would that be the issue? I thought Laravel was doing the encoding and reading?

Cheers

Comment: Could it be my version of PHP? Running 5.3.6 on live and 5.3.10 on local, both with mcrypt installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgraded PHP, turns out 5.3.6  is not enough for laravel 4. has to do with bcrypt I think

Answer (score 0):

Posted this as a comment before, but as it is the only possible reason I can imagine, I'll repost this as an answer.

If you're running two separate Laravel installations, you might have different encryption keys set in `app/config/app.php`. Make sure those are the same and it should work.